# What is the section labeled מענה לשון in a Chumash?

Tags: jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash, chumash

Looking at a sample page of the Chumash Simanim (for ex. [here](https://www.nehora.com/chumash-simanim-with-rashi-and-shabbos-tefillos/#PhotoSwipe1703702151538)), I see the Torah text, Targum Onkelos, Rashi, and, at the foot of the page, a section labeled מענה לשון. What is this last section, and where can I read more about it? Is it a common text to include in a Chumash? Why is it included in this one? Googling I have only found information about the gravesite Maaneh Lashon prayers, but this appears to be something that runs along and accompanies the entire Torah text.

Comment: Did you check the introduction to the work? Usually the commentaries included are defined.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to more than the sample pages available online. The publisher’s description doesn’t seem to help, and the nature and value of this section is something I’d like to know about before purchasing a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%99-%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93.html) identifies it as:

> ביאור על דקדוקי המילים, כללים, פיסוק טעמים, מסורות ועוד

and [this page](https://tora-shlema.co.il/product/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/) as

> מדור חדש של הערות על כל מילה שיש בה שום דיון בקדמוננו המדקדקים ,בחומש
> ובהפטרות וחמש מגילות , המוגשים בשפה קלה ומובנת ,כאשר אנחנו מציינים
> מאיזה כלל דקדוקי נובע כל שינוי .

ie grammatical notes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!

Comment: @t.w. you’re welcome. If it’s what you needed then please do use the check mark to tell others that your question has been answered.